# Display Integer Data in Format of String in the Shapefile Table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, field-calculator

I have a Field in a Shapefile which has 3 unique Integer values as

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

but I want to display them in table as string like

```
1 - A
2 - B
3 - C
```

so eventually in the table will be A, B or C but keep the actual data in integer format behind the scene
Can you please let me know how to do this is ArcGIS

Comment: Not in a shapefile, as a feature class in a geodatabase yes. You can create a domain and associate it with the field then your attribute editor, attribute table and identify will all show the letter instead of the number by default. If you must keep this a shapefile you have no other option but to add a new (text) field and calculate the values but this will mean if the original value is changed the calculated letter will no longer match.

Comment: Hi Michael, so we can not do these thing using `Field Calculator`?

Comment: Not as I understand your question. You can have a domain in a geodatabase to store numbers but show text but that is not available to shapefiles.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was planning to do! to `To store numbers(integer) but show them as text`

Comment: A point for comment from @MichaelMiles-Stimson's first comment is "if you must keep this a shapefile".  Do you need this as a shapefile, or is there a reason you can't recreate your shapefile as a geodatabase feature class?

Comment: Well I was really interested to know how Esri Electric Data set been doing this in Phase Designation fields. so I got that the sub-type and domain is doing thsi

Comment: The Esri Electrical dataset will be in a geodatabase, meaning the domains and subtypes are available

Comment: If you install an extension for ArcGis and have it active there is more than just the default Esri code running. Not having used that extension I'd just be guessing but it sounds like that software has overridden ITableView or IFeatureClass in the ArcObjects namespace for shapefiles if what you say is correct. It certainly isn't default Esri behavior... which is, after all, what you *buy extensions for*.